# llamar atributos a traves de varias relaciones y select multiple

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Soy relativamente nuevo trabajando en Laravel, y estoy aprendiendo sobre la marcha, en esta oportunidad me estanque, y donde estoy no puedo ver videos para tratar de resolver la duda que tengo en estos momomentos, ojala me pideran ayudar.

Tengo una relación entre 3 tablas,

una se llama instancias,
otra se llama servidor,
y otra se llama intanciasservidor.

Tengo un campo donde escojo un servidor, y a partir de ese campo, me rellena otro campo con las instancias que estan guardadas en ese servidor.

Pues como esa relacion esta en la tabla instanciasservidor, me trae los IDS, con los que esta relacionado, pero no se como traer el nombre de la instancia, pues ese esta en la tabla de las intancias, y como estoy usando JQUERY, no se como hacer para traer el nombre cuando se realiza el change.

En la siguiente imagen muestro como lo llevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el select donde traigo los servidores

```
<label>Seleccionar Servidor</label>

<select name="servidor" id="servidor" class="chosen"> 
<option value="">Seleccionar Servidor</option> 
@foreach($servidores as $servidor) 
<option value="{{ $servidor->id }}">{{ $servidor->ip }}</option> 
@endforeach 
</select>

<br><br>
```

Acá se cargan las instancias:

```
<label>Instancias</label>
<select name="instancia" id="instancia" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%"> 
<option value="" >Selecciona un Servidor Primero</option>
</select>
```

y esta es la funcion que cree para llenar la información en el anterior campo

```
<script> 
var rutaConsulta55 = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.instancia') }}"; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
selectChange55(); 
}); 

function selectChange55(){ 
$('#servidor').on('change', function(e){ 
var idServer = $(this).val(); 
ajaxSelect55(idServer); 

}); 
} 

function ajaxSelect55(id)
    { 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    headers: { 
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
    },
    url: rutaConsulta55, 
    data: {id: id}, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    beforeSend: function(){ 
    } 
    }).done(function(response) { 
    var html = '<option value="" >Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
    $.each(response.ixs, function(i, elem){ 
    html += '<option value="'+ elem.id + 'class="chosen" name="instancias[]" id = "instancias"'  + '">'+ elem.id_instancia + '</option>' 
    }); 
    $('#instancia').html(html); 
    }).fail(function(data) { 

    }); 
    }  
</script>
```

Pero como repito, no se como hacer para traer el nombre.

Y lo mas dificil, con lo que me he dado de topes contra la pared, lo fundamental realmente, y es, que cuando selecciono varias, solo me guarda la primera que haya seleccionado, se que me falta algo en la funcion store, pero realmente no he encontrado como.

Gracias por leer. Ojala me puedan ayudar.

EDIT

Controlador

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Indisponibilidades;
use App\SistemasOperativos;
use App\Servidores;
use App\Ixs;
use App\Instancias;



class IndisponibilidadController extends Controller
{    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $items = Indisponibilidades::with('parentIndisponibilidades','server','ixs','sxi','instancias')->get();

        return view('admin.indisponibilidadVistas.index', compact('items'));
    }


    public function consultarInstancias(Request $request) 
    { 
        $servidores = $request->id;

        $instancias = Ixs::where('id_servidor', $servidores)->get(); 

        $respuesta2 = array(); 
        $respuesta2['ixs'] = $instancias->toArray(); 
        return response()->json($respuesta2); 
    }



    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $instancias2 = Instancias::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
        $servidores = Servidores::orderBy('ip','asc')->get(); 
        $ixs = Ixs::orderBy('id_instancia','asc')->get(); 
          return view ('admin.indisponibilidadVistas.create', compact('servidores','instancias2','ixs')); 
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Indisponibilidades::create($request->all());

        //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));
        return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.indisponibilidadRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $item = Indisponibilidades::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.indisponibilidadVistas.edit', compact('item'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $item = Indisponibilidades::findOrFail($id);
        $item->update($request->all());
        //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
        return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.indisponibilidadRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Indisponibilidades::destroy($id);

        return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_destroy'));
    }
}
```

Comment: podrías agregar el código de tú controlador?

Comment: Si sr, En un momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta función pude hacer lo del select multiple

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   //Indisponibilidades::create($request->all()); 
    $intancia = $request->get('instancia'); 
    $nivel = $request->get('nivel'); 
    $servidor = $request->get('servidor'); 
    $hora_inicio = $request->get('hora_inicio'); 
    $hora_final = $request->get('hora_final'); 
    $descripcion = $request->get('descripcion'); 

    $Indisponibilidades = []; 

    foreach($intancia as $insta) 
    { 
    if(! empty($insta)) 
    { 
    // Get the current time 
        $now = date('Y-m-d');

        // Formulate record that will be saved 
        $Indisponibilidades[] = [ 
        'instancia' => $insta, 
        'nivel' => $nivel, 
        'servidor' => $servidor, 
        'hora_inicio' => $hora_inicio, 
        'hora_final' => $hora_final, 
        'descripcion' => $descripcion, 
        'updated_at' => $now, 
        'created_at' => $now 
        ]; 
    } 
    } 

    Indisponibilidades::insert($Indisponibilidades); 

    //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store')); 
    return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.indisponibilidadRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store')); 

}
```

Y Con esto en mi vista, para que me envie el arreglo directamente.

```
<div class="row">  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
      <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">
          <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Instancia</label>
          <br>
            <select name="instancia[]" id="instancia" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
               <option value="">Selecciona un servidor primero</option>
            </select>
          <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agradezco a las personas que me ayudaron.

Answer (score 1):

Dudo que sea la forma mas eficiente, pero si tienes creadas las relaciones en los modelos, puedes intentar utilizar el with() para que se traiga la tabla relacionada con sus campos.

```
InstanciasServidor::all()->with('instancias')->get()
```

Lo ideal seria utilizar tablas pivotes (pivot tables), para lo cual seria bueno que vieras algún tutorial corto y sencillo (como el de Styde por ejemplo).